# How to add title/button to a UINavigationController added inside a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

For some reason, I have to add a UINavagationController() inside a UIViewController(), so I did the following in the view controller class:

```
class someViewController: UIViewController {
    private let myNav = UINavigationController()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.addChildViewController(myNav)
        self.view.addSubview(myNav.view)
        myNav.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        myNav.view.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).active = true
        myNav.view.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leftAnchor).active = true
        myNav.view.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.rightAnchor).active = true
        myNav.view.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(nil, constant: 44).active = true
        myNav.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }
}
```

The navigation controller is added & showing up correctly. Then I try to add a title (or Done button) to the navigation bar, however the items just don't show up. I tried a few things like this:

```
self.navigationItem.title = "some title"
myNav.navigationItem.title = "some title"
myNav.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnDone
```

What's the right way to do it in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use this simple code to add a navigation bar :

```
    let navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 66)) // Offset by 20 pixels vertically to take the status bar into account


    // Create a navigation item with a title
    let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
    navigationItem.title = "Title"

    // Create left and right button for navigation item
    let leftButton =  UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style:   UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "btn_clicked:")
    let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Right", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: nil)

    // Create two buttons for the navigation item
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton

    // Assign the navigation item to the navigation bar
    navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]

    // Make the navigation bar a subview of the current view controller
    self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)
```

Comment: Thanks. I know this way, but when I use `UINavigationBar` method, I am having trouble to make the top corners rounded. I found a solution in SO, but when I make the top corners rounded with the `CAShapeLayer` solution, then the title/button disappears somehow. So I try to explore the `UINavigationController` option again.